# Adding custom action filters with inheriting of ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action-filter

Not sure if this is any questions that should take place here but...
I've wanted to add some custom action filters... thing is that every article I have read until now, had inheriting of `CustomFilterName : ActionFilterAttribute`
. When I've created my MVC project, there was no file called ActionFilterAttribute... tried to find out how to add one but there is literally no info beside inheriting. Is this something that is automatically add? Or I somehow have to add it by my self?

Comment: Read [Understanding Action Filters](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) where you found **The ASP.NET MVC framework includes a base ActionFilterAttribute class. This class implements both the IActionFilter and IResultFilter interfaces and inherits from the Filter class.**

Comment: @Div 'In order to make it easier for you to implement a custom action filter, the ASP.NET MVC framework includes a base ActionFilterAttribute class. This class implements both the IActionFilter and IResultFilter interfaces and inherits from the Filter class.' I haven't found it so far ;e..I mean, I do not have this class ;o

Comment: What do you mean by no found, it's Inherited class of `System.Web.Mvc`

Comment: Make sure your project reference `System.Web.Mvc` assembly.